# Location Marker Pin on Esri map is changing direction when we navigate. How to stop rotating of map pin

Tags: arcgis-android, arcgis-ios

I am using a custom map marker icon which works well as expected. However as I navigate , the direction of the marker pin on map changes. I have tried changing the coarse symbol and heading symbol as well. But that doesn't work. Here's the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXawl.jpg

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid this when `LocationDisplayManager.AutoPanMode == NAVIGATION` as it rotates the map to align it with the direction of travel.  You can avoid this by using `LocationDisplayManager.AutoPanMode == LOCATION` if that mode works for your app.